# Why are template type parameters not visible/existent as opposed to non-type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In a template class that contains another template class (for what it matters, an exchangeable storage representation of... whatever), I thought that instead of passing in serveral template parameters **down**, it would be more elegant to pass in one instantiation of the inner template and reach parameters **up** again instead.

Why not! Sure this works, and it's way more elegant!

Now, maybe the above is a bit hard to understand, so let's see some (almost compilable) code of what I've been trying to do:

```
template<typename T, int n> struct foo
{
    // using alias_of_T = T;
};

template<typename FOO> struct bar
{
    FOO _foo;

    // this works just fine!?
    static constexpr int size = FOO::n;

    // this indeed works, but... bleh
    // using type_t = typename FOO::alias_of_T;

    // this does not work?
    using type_t = typename FOO::T;

    type_t whatever() { return ...; }
};

//...

int main()
{
    bar<foo<int, 3>> zoo;
    ...
```

The surprise is that `FOO`'s template parameter `T` is not accessible. But even more surprising, it is perfectly possible to access `n`.

What is the rationale behind that?

Is there a more elegant way than using `FOO::alias_of_T`?

### Re: Why does it work for the non-type parameter?

It turns out I'm too stupid to read my own code! There was (kudos to @Barry) indeed a "different size", i.e. a `constexpr size = n` alias in the original (not trimmed down, not-foo-bar) code, which I seem to have totally overlooked. That explains why it "works fine" for the non-type parameter, no surprise there. Well, that's embarrassing, you really gotta be able to read the code you typed yourself properly...

Comment: *"// this works just fine!?"* No it doesn't. It just looks like it does because you don't instantiate `size`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/2jPoCOJwqTmdmcBI

Comment: ^ bingo. Taking the original code and just adding `std::cout << decltype(zoo)::size << '\n';` (and of course making `.whatever()` return `type_t{}`) gives the same error. So, the answer to the final question, for both type and non-type template arguments, is no. :P That said, it's surprising to me that the validity of `size` (existence of `n`) isn't checked until it's used, but that's probably a logical consequence of some template parsing rule I'm not familiar enough with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The surprise is that `FOO`'s template parameter `T` is not accessible. But even more surprising, it is perfectly possible to access `n`.

I suppose that depends on your definition of perfect. It's not actually possible to access `n`, but the point at which you'd discover this is a little different. Indeed, if you tried to *use* `size`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int n>
struct foo { };

template <typename FOO>
struct bar {
    static constexpr int size = FOO::n;
};

int main() {
    bar<foo<int, 3>> zoo;
    std::cout << zoo.size << '\n'; // error: n is not a member of foo<int, 3>
}
```

This is because of [[temp.inst]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#3):

> [...] in particular, the initialization (and any associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

In your example, nothing required the static data member to exist, so its initialization didn't happen yet - and it's that initialization that would have been ill-formed.

If you had directly tried to access the name "n", you'd see the same thing:

```
template <typename T, int n>
struct foo { };

template <typename FOO>
struct bar {
    int array[FOO::n]; // error
};

int main() {
    bar<foo<int, 3>> zoo;
}
```

Comment: While it _looks like_ you got it exactly, I can assure you that this is not the case. There exists a function `clear()` which does, well, clear the contents of said storage. The verbatim implementation is, pretty unspectacular: `void clear() noexcept { for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) storage[i] = 0; }`. Calling the `clear` function, which most certainly _does_ instantiate `size`,  compiles and to all appearances "works just fine" (i.e. zero warnings with max warnings enabled).

Comment: @Damon - Then you wouldn't mind showing it in your post instead of describing it vaguely in comments. And are you by any chance building with MSVC?

Comment: @Damon Even aside from the issue that this is a hard compile error, the code you posted should trigger a warning for signed-unsigned mismatch. You sure there's not some other `size` and you are invoking this specific `clear()`?

Comment: @Barry: OK, this is where it gets emabrrassing, you're right. I was just going to post the original code on godbolt, turns out there is **indeed** a different `size` (an alias for the template parameter) that I completely overlooked. Which is probably the reason it works. So it turns out I'm only too stupid to read my own code... :(